# issues with CPU utilization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am running ubuntu EC2 small instance with ruby on rails and mysql in the instance, my rails app consists of delayed jobs.

I have observed it suddenly my instance CPU utilization spikes out more then 70 % and the persists for more then a minute.

Ruby on rails app is not a CPU intense app, but I am not able to figure why and where exactly its happening,I have activated the Cloud watch monitoring, and also created alarm .

Kindly suggest me to figure out some tools to figure out which processes is a CPU intense.

How to I handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `top` and see what's at the top of the list when the CPU usage is high.